# Setting Text Editor to Read Only in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I came across 'Set Read-Only' option (It sets the text to read only) in Notepad++, so I was wondering whether Visual Studio 2010 has this option. My Notepad++ Screenshot is given below. I am a novice so please forgive me if this is stupid question....!

My Notepad++ Screenshot

I don't have enough Reputation points for the Screenshot so here is the link

http://www.flickr.com/photos/93046100@N08/8453289064/in/photostream

Comment: no screenshot is attached to your question...

Comment: I don't have enough Reputation points for the Screenshot so here is the link 
http://www.flickr.com/photos/93046100@N08/8453289064/in/photostream

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio doesnt have such functionality.

To achieve similar effect you have two options:

1) Set 'Read-Only' flag on respective files at OS level (go to file location -> File Properties -> Read Only checkbox). Downside of this approach is that you have to mark each file separately.

2) Add your project to any SVN and lock whole project or any file/files. Benefits of this approach are: multiple files can be processed at the same time, only one who locked files can unlock them